# Wrong result while trying to sum/rest values from different inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a result (after sum/rest) from two different values, for example I have a `Total var = 500` then I have `two inputs... one for MXN and the other for USD, I also have a USD var = 17.5` what I want to do is that when I type a number on both inputs (MXN or USD) display a sum (for money received) and a rest (for change, in case that the received money were more than 500 or my Total value), at the moment I have this code, but just work for one input instead of both, how can I solve this?

Here is an [working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybaqjm)

**EDIT:**

Now I got both inputs working as expected but know I'm facing another issue... I have one label to show change value (when money received > total) and one to show when money received <= total.

For example... Total = 500, received = 450, my label need to show I need: $50, but if my total = 500, received = 600 I need to show: Change: $100

However here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var dolar = 17.50;
  
  $('#Total').on('keyup', function() {
    var valor = $(this).val();
    
    if (valor == "") {
      $('#TotalLbl').text("$00.00");
    } else {
      $('#TotalLbl').text("Total: $" + parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2));
    }
  });
  
  $('#MXN').on('keyup', function() {
    var valor = $(this).val();

    if (valor == "") {
      $('#Received').text("$00.00");
    } else {
      $('#Received').text("Received: $" + parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2));
      var falta = ($('#Total').val() - valor);
      $('#INeedThisTo0').text("Change: $" + parseFloat(falta).toFixed(2));
    }
  });

  $('#USD').on('keyup', function() {
    var valor = $(this).val() * dolar;
    if (valor == "") {
      $('#Received').text("$00.00");
    } else {
      $('#Received').text("Received: $" + parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2));
      var falta = ($('#Total').val() - valor);
      $('#INeedThisTo0').text("Change: $" + parseFloat(falta).toFixed(2));
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input placeholder="Total.." type="number" id="Total" />

<input placeholder="MXN.." type="number" id="MXN" />

<input placeholder="USD.." type="number" id="USD" />

<br>

<label id="TotalLbl"></label>

<label id="Received"></label>

<label id="INeedThisTo0"></label>

<label id="Change"></label>
```

Comment: Write a single function that calculates the result you want based on all 3 inputs. Then call this same function in the `keyup` for all the inputs.

Comment: but just work for one input instead of both, how can I solve this?

Comment: May I ask to which one it work good mxn or dollar ?

Comment: @Osama Works for MXN or USD, for both not

Comment: Please I understand the code you write it depends upon the keyup event for each text box in your form what you mean by ( both)?

Comment: if you already have a working example (the codepen), then why not just use that? Or is there some difference in your requirements? If so, please clarify the difference.

Comment: @Osama For example... If my total is = 500 and I type 400 in MXN input my received label shows 400 and change label shows 100, then when I type for example 3 in USD input (3*17.5=52.5) I expect that my received label shows 400+52.5 = 452.5 and my change label 500-452.5=47.5 but instead of that only shows me the value from USD ignoring my current MXN value thats why I said that only works for one input MXN or USD

Comment: @ADyson Now I have my inputs working properly but know I have another issue when showing my result, I edit the code and added a new codepen link with working example with my new changes

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#USD').on('keyup', function() {
var valor =( $(this).val() * dolar)+$('MXN').val();

$('#MXN').on('keyup', function() {
var valor = $(this).val()+($('USD').val()*dolar);
```

Convert the valor value in both function as this